# Access violation when closing the form that has floating component

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I have a C++Builder VCL application that has some dynamically created components on it. These components should be able to dock and undock from a Panel.

The problem is, if the user closes the form while one of these components are undocked (Floating), I get an error:

> First chance exception at $50C278EF. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x50c278ef: read of address 0x00000010'. Process Project1.exe (8004)

Here is a simplified sample that demonstrate the problem:

The HPP:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ExtCtrls.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TPanel *Panel1;
    TPanel *Panel2;
    void __fastcall FormCreate(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall FormDestroy(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
    TPanel *Panel3;
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

The CPP

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    Panel3 = new TPanel((TComponent*)nullptr);
    Panel3->Parent = Panel1;
    Panel3->Width = 50;
    Panel3->Height = 50;
    Panel3->DragKind = dkDock;
    Panel3->DragMode = dmAutomatic;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
{
    delete Panel3;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The DFM

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 128
    Top = 48
    Width = 409
    Height = 217
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    DockSite = True
    TabOrder = 0
    object Panel2: TPanel
      Left = 216
      Top = 8
      Width = 185
      Height = 97
      Caption = 'Panel2'
      DragKind = dkDock
      DragMode = dmAutomatic
      TabOrder = 0
    end
  end
end
```

In this example, if `Panel3` is Floating and the user closes that form, we get the exception.

Comment: The error message is telling you that a null pointer is being accessed. You are clearly running inside the debugger, so where is the debugger showing you that the code is actually crashing? In any case, you shouldn't use the `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` events in C++ at all.  They are Delphi idioms that can cause *illegal behavior* in C++.  Use the Form's actual constructor and destructor instead. And if you assign the Form as the `Owner` for `Panel3` instead of `nullptr` then you don't need to explicitly call `delete Panel3;` at all, the Form will handle that for you when the Form is destroyed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The reson I'm using `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` is because setting the parent of a component inside the constructor where handle is not created has proven to be problematic. Also this was a simple example, and I need to be able to create and delete these components during the run-time as needed. Relying on the form to destroy everything, is not going to work for me. The debugger shows the error is happening inside the `IsFormSizeStored` function.

Comment: Anything that can be done in `OnCreate` can be done in the constructor, and done *legally*.  Same with `OnDestroy` and the destructor. The problem with `OnCreate`/`OnDestroy` is WHEN they are called.  They CAN be called *before* your Form's constructor and *after* its destructor, respectively. Because the VCL is written in Delphi, the events are following Delphi lifetime semantics, which are different than C++ lifetime semantics.